# how to force a polynomial regression to be very flexible for big sharp turns while reducing flexibility for small turns

Tags: r, regression, polynomials

Is it possible to force a polynomial regression to be very flexible for big sharp turns while reducing flexibility for small turns?

The reason is that I have a variabele y which depends on x for which I am sure there is a positive correlation, although my dataset contains some noise. This is why I do not want a wiggly line for x between 1 and 75 as in the graph below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

x <- c(1:100)
y <- c(1,3,6,12,22,15,13,11,5,1,3,6,12,22,11,5,1,3,6,12,22,11,5,5,9,10,1,6,12,22,15,13,11,5,-1,-12,-23,6,12,22,11,5,1,3,6,12,22,11,5,-11,-22,-9,12,22,11,5,9,10,18,1,3,6,12,22,15,13,11,5,-5, -9, -12,6,12,22,11,5,1,3,6,12,22,11,5,1,3,6,12,22,11,5,9,10,18,28,37,50,90,120,150,200)
y <- y + x

df <- data.frame(x, y)

model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 6, raw = TRUE), data = df)

predictions <- model %>% predict(df)
df <- cbind(df, predictions) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y), size = 0.1) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = x, y = predictions), colour="blue", size=0.1)
```

[image]

I can alter the model to:

```
model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE), data = df)
```

Which gives this graph:

[image]

In this case the model is without wigglyness for x between 0 and 90 although it is missing the flexibility to make the turn around x is 90.

I am not looking for a specific solution for this example dataset. I am looking for a solution to have a polynomial regression flexible enough to make sharp (big) turns, although reducing wigglyness for small turns at the same time. (Maybe this can be solved by a limit to make a maximum of n turns?)

I want to use it automated at several datasets. For this reason I do not want to specify different ranges of x for different models.

Thank you!

I have also tried using gam from mgcv, although this gives similar results:

```
mygam <- gam(y ~ s(x, k = 7), data = df)
```

[image]

```
mygam <- gam(y ~ s(x, k = 3), data = df)
```

[image]

This graph is based on pmax(p1, p2) where p1 and p2 are two polynomials:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps use pmax(p1, p2) where p1 and p2 are two polynomials, possibly lines.

Comment: I may try the curve fitting models as illustrated in this article https://www.statforbiology.com/nonlinearregression/usefulequations.

Comment: This is definitely better done with splines.  Take a look at `mgcv:gam()`.  If you just need a nice plot use `ggplot2::geom_smooth()` which make use of loess for small datasets and gam for larger.

Comment: @ Brian Montgomery. I have added graphs made with mgcv:gam() although these give similar results.

Comment: @ Xiang Thank you, is there a specific model you would suggest from these?

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck Interesting idea. Although when the wiggly line is above the smooth line the wigglyness is still in the endresult. See added graph. The red line is pmax. Blue and green the smooth and wiggly line respectively.